Not able to connect mongo using spark with SSL
I am working with spark version 3.4.2, I want to connect mongoDB using pyspark, I have been given 2 pem files by database dept, first file ("CA.pem") is having 2 certificate content like as follows:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
GHHSBBBMMM,,,,........
-----END CERTIFICATE-------
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ABCBBBCCCBBB..... 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Second file (mongo.pem) above has certificate and then Private key content like as follows:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
LLKKIISOOSSS,,,........ 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
ANNmmmMMM .... .... 
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I have read in one of the stack overflow question here How to make connection from mongo-spark connector to mongodb when only TLS/ssl enable for mongo DB?
 that I need to first changed my first file "CA.pem" to "CA.cert" and then using keytool to ".jks" format, like this :
keytool -importcert -file CA.pem -alias ca-cert-alias -keystore trustStoremongo.jks -storepass pass

After this I can use it in spark, like :
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2 \
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStoremongo.jks \
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass \
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keyStore.jks \
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStoremongo.jks \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keyStore.jks \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass \
testmongoProd.py

But after all of this I still getting an error:
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:579)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:444)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:298)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)

And when I only use truststore and not keystore, then:
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2 --driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/cert/trustStoremongo.jks --driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/certs/trustStoremongo.jks --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass testmongoProd.py

and I get following error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:795)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:365)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:55)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:49)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:793)
        ... 25 more
24/08/27 18:34:13 INFO cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server np-pri-mongo-db-02.nayapay.com:27003
com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Unable to create default SSLContext
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.getSslContext(SocketStreamFactory.java:90)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.create(SocketStreamFactory.java:78)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:125)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1912)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:99)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.getSslContext(SocketStreamFactory.java:88)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:73)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:278)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getTrustManagers(SSLContextImpl.java:1036)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:1006)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:156)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1905)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:795)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:365)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:55)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:49)
        ... 19 more

I am giving right password, and I have checked its existance using "keytool -list" as well. Anyone having experience regarding this ?

The database department provided you the server certificate with the private key? These guys are not very smart in terms of security. They should not disclose the private key. Or did they create a client certificate for you?

It is a CA-signed client certificate key.

@Muhammad Affan did you find any solution for this ? if yes can you please share the same

sure @Nagaraj,
There are multiple steps for this:

mkdir -p /your-loc/software/jks
cp org-ssl.cer /your-loc/software/jks
sudo keytool --import -alias chat03 -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
-file /your-loc/software/jks/org-ssl.cer
Run your spark file having mongo connectivity (spark code) in it.


Elaborating my 4th point, you can run your spark file using this command:
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2 --driver-java-options "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" --driver-java-options "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= /your-loc/software/jks/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yourpassword" testmongoProd.py
